Combinatorial number system and generating function
The combinatorial number system is stated as follows:
Prove that for a given positive integer $k$ each positive integer $n$ admits a unique representation in the form
$$
n=\binom{b_1}{1}+\binom{b_2}{2}+\cdots+\binom{b_k}{k},
$$
where $0 \leq b_1<b_2<\cdots<b_k$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system
For example, for $k=2$, we have the following representations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& 1=\binom{0}{1}+\binom{2}{2} \\
& 2=\binom{1}{1}+\binom{2}{2} \\
& 3=\binom{0}{1}+\binom{3}{2} \\
& 4=\binom{1}{1}+\binom{3}{2} \\
& 5=\binom{2}{1}+\binom{3}{2} \\
& 6=\binom{0}{1}+\binom{4}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
I have managed to prove the above theorem. I heard my teacher say that the above theorem can be proven using generating functions. How can this be done?
